# Mount NAS share works by hand but not from boot even after networking

Tags: networking, mount, boot, systemctl

The problem is on a Debian  machine, I use a Ubuntu one, and the same share is loaded in a Raspberry.

I put the entry for the mount in `/etc/fstab` but it works only with `sudo mount -a` and not on the boot.

I suspect the problem was that the network was not available at the mount time, so I wrote a service snippet (following [this tutorial](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/start-systemd-service-after-nfs-mount/)).

In brief:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/mnt-mune_NAS.mount` containing

```
[Unit]
Description=Mount NFS Share from nfs NASS
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
After=network-online.target remote-fs.target
Before=umount.target

[Mount]
What=192.168.1.20:/volume1/cartella_mune
Where=/mnt/mune_NAS
Type=nfs
Options=defaults

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then I've refreshed the server `sudo systemctl start mnt-mune_NAS.mount` and I checked with `systemctl status mnt-mune_NAS.mount`:

```
● mnt-mune_NAS.mount - Mount NFS Share from nfs NASS
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mnt-mune_NAS.mount; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (mounted) since Tue 2022-04-26 22:57:53 CEST; 3min 8s ago
      Where: /mnt/mune_NAS
       What: 192.168.1.20:/volume1/cartella_mune
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 19047)
     Memory: 32.0K
        CPU: 7ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/mnt-mune_NAS.mount
```

Finally I made it to be executed on boot `sudo systemctl enable mnt-mune_NAS.mount`.

After boot `sudo reboot; exit` the share was not mounted `mount | grep NAS`.

What is wrong?

Comment: What is the status after the reboot?

Comment: did you perform daemon-reload step ?

Comment: @Archemar Sorry, I forget to mention it, I did. (As I followed, the guide, but I think that as I wouldl reboot right after, it wasn't really necessary). Anyway I did it.

Comment: @jsbillings After the reboot the response to `systemctl status mnt-mune_NAS.mount` is ```● mnt-mune_NAS.mount - Mount NFS Share from nfs NASS
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mnt-mune_NAS.mount; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2022-04-28 15:53:30 CEST; 2min 18s ago
      Where: /mnt/mune_NAS
       What: 192.168.1.20:/volume1/cartella_mune
        CPU: 3ms

Warning: some journal files were not opened due to insufficient permissions.``` with the red bullet

Comment: New information: I add, by hand- the NAS's share by **hand** and the service status has the green bullet

Comment: I bet the mount point can’t start on boot because it needs the network. You might want to add network-online.target as a requirement.

Comment: @jsbillings Isn't it what already is in the Unit section:`After=network-online.target remote-fs.target` ? Does it go in another section?

Comment: @mune72 you are right, I missed that. I suspect there might be more info if you run the status command with sudo.

Comment: @jsbillings actually I did and the output is in my first comment replying to you. It says "insufficient permission" and not "host unreachable" (or similar -as the network should fail), but it mounts by hand -even with systemctl start-.

Comment: @mune72 that error about insufficient permission is that you can’t read the journal (system logs).  We’re you root or sudo when you ran the command?

Comment: @jsbillings No, I was just a plain user: I thought it was enough just to read. Tomorrow I'll try as root.

Comment: @jsbillings The output for the user root is
https://pastetext.net/udtbi4fmzf
the bullet was red.

Comment: @mune72 url doesn’t work for me,

Comment: @jsbillings Sorry, I made all of these to short the comment text but I end up to make it longer :(!  Try out this [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/gv1fzmnU)